# Upgraded my webapplication to use OJDBC8.jar. but Websphere8.5 refers to old version ojdbc6 and returns nosuchmethoderror

Tags: websphere, nosuchmethoderror, ojdbc

Error 500: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.createOracleArray(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/sql/Array; (loaded from file:/sysap/oracle/instantclient_11_2/ojdbc6.jar by com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader@96620801) called from class com.model.dao.TypeKeysDAO (loaded from file:/opt/WebSphere/8_5/AppServerBase1/profiles/AppServerBase1/installedApps/System_Cell/MyEnterprise.ear/MyEnterpriseWeb.war/WEB-INF/classes/ by com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader@3edbaa21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old copy of the JDBC jar appears to be associated with a JDBC provider defined in your configuration. The error message indicates that the class was loaded by WebSphere's ExtClassLoader, which is the loader that contains JDBC driver class paths. You'll need to remove the old JDBC provider, update its class path, or make it an "isolated" resource provider (which gives it a separate class loader that must be explicitly associated with an application) in order to get it out of the view of your application.

If there's some technical reason that you need ojdbc6.jar in the resource provider class path but need to reference ojdbc8.jar just within your application (not through a server-configured datasource), then you'll need to do some class loader configuration wizardry to make it work. The most reliable solution would be to create a shared library containing the new jar, set it to use an isolated class loader, and associate it with your EAR or WAR.

Answer (score 0):

`ojdbc6.jar` is definitely there in the class path of the application. To locate from where it's loaded, you can login to the WebSphere Application server console (`https://localhost:<admin-port>/ibm/console`) and check the class loading details of your application.
This will show the list of classes/jars that are loaded for your application. Locate ojdbc6.jar from the list and see it's path.

You either would have added the `ojdbc6.jar` as a shared library or bundled in along with your Application (`WEB-INF/lib` directory) OR mentioned it in the class loader of the server itself.

Answer (score 0):

file:/sysap/oracle/instantclient_11_2/ojdbc6.jar  this is the sharedlibrary referenced by the EAR. I have added the ojdbc8.jar in this location and now the issue is fixed.